# New build Win7 workstation fails to see the DC (Server 2k8 ) but can see the DHCP/network just fine

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, windows-7

We have a new-build windows7 64 bit workstation that can't see the Windows Server 2k8r2 Domain Controller and therefore can't join the domain.  It is connecting to the network just fine, all drivers load correctly and DHCP (a linux DHCP box) assigns an IP address correctly.  However since the machine can't see the domain controller it can't join the domain and can't access its DNS services (the DC also acts as the DNS)

Other machines on the same unmanaged switch have no issues.

We are stuck.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

> since the machine can't see the domain controller it can't join the domain and **can't access its DNS services**

This is nonsensical. You must use the DC's DNS service on the workstation in order for it to be able to "see" the DC.

It sounds to me as if your workstation isn't doing this. You say you are using DHCP, what DNS server/s are configured on your DHCP scope? You must only use your DC as the DNS server for internal clients, no other DNS servers must be used.

Comment: I agree.  I guess my limited knowedge is showing.  The DHCP passes out a perfectly valid IP address and the workstation can see the network.  However the WS cannot see the domain controller nor register with the domain.  Neither can ping nor communicate with the other as far as we can tell.  However the WS CAN see other machines on the network and ping/navigate to them.  I hope this clarifies my earlier post.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough. Is your workstation using the DC's IP address for DNS?

Answer (score 0):

Having never tried to get a Windows client to join a domain following accepting a lease from a non-Windows DHCP server, the following is a bit of a guess...

Firstly, using an "unauthorised" DHCP server - could this be affecting the way that the Network Location Awareness (NLA) service determines what sort of network you're plugged in to.  This, could possible be causing the Windows Firewall to be in "public" network mode.

Also, agree with ThatGraemeGuy - are you dishing out your DNS server address(es), such that the AD service location (SRV) records can be found?